# How do I get a UITextField to accept focus without showing the keyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to find a way to prevent the keyboard from appearing when the user taps on a TextField but could`t find a way to do it.

I tried this code after I linked my textField to delegate and still it did not work for me, the code was logging but the keyboard did appear.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { 
    NSLog(@"BeginEditing");
    return YES;
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

When I return with `NO` I lose the focus from the textField, which I need.

The textFields I have are filled with values from a buttons on the same view, thats why I don't want the keyboard to appear, and at the same time I want the user to select the textField they want to fill.

Comment: [textField resignFirstResponder]; will not be called there...

Comment: what do you want to do when keeping focus on textfield and when the keyboard is not up?

Comment: i have a buttons that will fill values to the textField, buttons are on the same view. imagine it like a calculator with 4 textFields. @samfisher

Comment: means when user click button ,button value fill in the textfield???am i right??

Comment: @ParasJoshi yes your are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you just want user to select the textfield to fill and does not want to keyboard to show up then you can do the following:

- add tag to your textfields
- change the code to this:

> ```
> -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
> {
>     selectedTextFieldTag = textField.tag;
>     return NO;
> }
> ```

use `selectedTextField` value to identify which textfield to fill in your code. `return NO` will not allow keyboard to appear.

Comment: add `selectedTextFieldTag ` as a NSUInteger to ur class.

Comment: this is great, but one problem, the blinking line will not appear in the textField

Answer (score 3):

This will help you for sure.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField {
UIView *dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
activeField.inputView = dummyView; // Hide keyboard, but show blinking cursor
return YES;
}
```

I tested and it is working for me. Hope this will be useful for others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

[textField resignFirstResponder]; will not be called because you are returning from the method before it can get called. Does that not fire a warning?

Try returning NO here or if that doesn't work, try disabling user-interaction on the text field:

```
[myTextField setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: this won't help because i want to user to select with textField to fill.

Comment: No need to downvote my answer... To be honest moving return YES to below resignFirstResponder should work. If you leave the control open but don't allow the user to enter anything I would think that goes against the Developer Guidelines...

Comment: i didn't down voted your answer, and i just tried it , it didn't work

Comment: Oh Sorry, I wonder who did. Well anyway, you may want to rethink how you are going to achieve your goal. I would disable userinteraction and use a invisible button over the field or something like that

Comment: thanx man , i`ll try to think of something like that but not now :P

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { 
NSLog(@"BeginEditing");
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;

}
```

Comment: @iArezki If you do this in iOS 7, you get a white line as this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946524/white-line-on-the-bottom-on-ios-7-with-uitextfield .Do you know the solution  for it?

Answer (score 0):

so here you just use flag int variable to assign the value to focused textfield

define `int i;` flag globally in .h or .m file

after that in textField Delegate method use bellow code...

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    if (textField == yourtextField1 ) {
        i=1;
    }
    else if (textField == yourtextField2 ) {
        i=2;
    }
    else if (textField == yourtextField3 ) {
        i=3;
    }
    else if (textField == yourtextField4 ) {
        i=4;
    }
    return NO;
}
-(IBAction)yourbutton1_Clicked:(id)sender{
           if( i == 1){
              yourtextField1.text=yourbutton1.titleLabel.text;
          }
          else if ( i == 2){
            yourtextField2.text=yourbutton1.titleLabel.text;
          }
          else if ( i == 3){
            yourtextField3.text=yourbutton1.titleLabel.text;
          }
          else if ( i == 4){
            yourtextField4.text=yourbutton1.titleLabel.text;
          }
          else{
              NSLog(@"Please Click On TextField");//here you can put AlertView Message
          }
}
```

and so on.......

also you can use common method with sender id of button and also tag......

Comment: sorry but you didn't understand me, i have 4 textField's, not 4 buttons, i have 10 buttons, each button holds a value, what i need is  lets say for example , user press on TextField2, then press the 2nd button to fill the field with number 2, then he select TextField4 the he press the 9th button to fill the textField with number 105.

Comment: You're probably better with an enum rather than an int. Doing that makes for messy code ;)