# Prevent resignFirstResponder (losing focus) in UITextField when user hides UIKeyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need the focus to stay in my UITextfield when the UIKeyboard is hidden.

I have a bluetooth scanner attached to the device and it needs to scan into the UITextField regardless of the UIKeyboard being on screen or not.

This has worked flawlessly for 5 years until recent iOS updates.

Comment: you have already checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082515/how-do-i-get-a-uitextfield-to-accept-focus-without-showing-the-keyboard

Comment: none of those will work for me.

Comment: Your logic bluetooth does not give you a notice when scanning something ?. I have worked with this before and the SDK scanner can hear a notice that this can simply make the textfield `setText`.

This is impossible for you?

Comment: There is no SDK implementation, the scanners work as just a simple keyboard.  Implementing every single scanner that is out there's SDK would be a nightmare.  I just want the UITextField and UIKeyboard to work as they use to.